# What encryption method opennms uses to save user password

Tags: php, encryption, opennms

I want to create user using opennms REST API. 
In reference link https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/17.0.0/guide-development/guide-development.html#_users 
it is mentioned that we can pass password by encrypting it using salted encryption algorithm. 
Which encryption method should i use in php when i want to create user in opennms using RESTAPI so that user can login into system once created?

Comment: According to https://blog.ropnop.com/cracking-opennms-password-hashes/, they are hashing with SHA-256 then base64 encoded.  Even though they use the word encryption, it is not encrypted, it is hashed.

Comment: @Devon Thank you for help. Can you please provide some more help? how can i decrypt password of users in php? in link you provided it is given in python.

Comment: You can't decrypt a hash.  You can try password_hash to create one, it allows for SHA2 algorithms, but I don't know specifically.